# How to know if booking is done through web from GetReservationRS

Tags: sabre

How to know if booking is done through web from GetReservationRS from Retrieve Itinerary service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can check the e-ticket numbers for that itinerary. But there are a lot of parameters shows that ticketing is successful or not. If you have any request / response examples generated by your implementation, I can give you more clear explanation.